# use variable name instead of column name in R function

Tags: r

In this:

```
y <- svytable(~date4a, design = Pew.w)
```

`date4a` is a column name.

I want to replace `date4a` with a variable. The variable of course, will refer to a column name.

E.g. something like:

```
col <- "date4a"

y <- svytable(~col, design = Pew.w)   #This doesnt' work
```

How may I do that?

Comment: In my opinion, don't. Youre only making your work harder to understand by breaking mental models of how R works.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: This is an `R` coding question, not a question about statistics. It is off topic here, but should be on topic on [SO]. If you wait, we will migrate it for you.

Comment: @gung please migrate it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that this is something that is really worth doing, you could try:

```
col <- my.data.frame$date4a
y   <- svytable(~col, design=Pew.w)
```